# In which context if at all is adequate to use implicitly unwrapped optionals?

Tags: swift, option-type

For example what I gather is that `@IBoutlet`s are implicitly unwrapped because it wouldn't make sense for them to be `nil` and such event would be only caused by an error in programming, making the subsequent crash a debugging step.

But in a `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` could I store the 
ViewControllers in object properties and have them implicitly unwrapped?

```
class SomeTransition: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning{

  var fromVC: UIViewController!
  var toVC: UIViewController!

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

        fromVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from)
        toVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to)
    }
}
```

Would in this case be legitimate/good practice to use implicitly unwrapped optionals since the transition wouldn't make sense if there were not the two viewControllers to transition from/to?

As an aside, would the storing of fromVC and toVC as properties create a memory cycle?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about implicitly-unwrapped `IBOutlet` optionals but apparently that doesn't go without concerns: https://cocoacasts.com/should-outlets-be-optionals-or-implicitly-unwrapped-optionals

I don't use Interface Builder so I can't speak to personal experience here.

> ...optionals indicate that a constant or variable is allowed to have
>   “no value”. Sometimes it’s clear from a program’s structure that an
>   optional will always have a value, after that value is first set. In
>   these cases, it’s useful to remove the need to check and unwrap the
>   optional’s value every time it’s accessed, because it can be safely
>   assumed to have a value all of the time.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html

But I can speak to transitioning objects and you certainly can force unwrap to- and from- view controllers in them but any kind of forced unwrapping makes some programmers nervous which is why you would most likely see a `guard` in animation objects:

```
func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

    guard let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from),
        let toViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to) else {

        return transitionContext.completeTransition(false)

    }

    ...
```

Sometimes objects can become bloated and traffic can become congested and everything doesn't always work all of the time as it should every time. That is why I prefer to use guards because I've experienced methods that don't always fire perfectly under stress and implicit unwrapping would have crashed the entire app whereas a guard wouldn't. Guards can also make debugging easier.

And as for creating unintended reference cycles, that is absolutely possible because I've experienced that also so if you do make the view controllers properties of the instance make them `weak` variables and verify that they're being deallocated.

Comment: When unwrapping optionals in `animateTransition` using a guard statement, is there a way to proceed with the view controller transition without animation if the guard statement fails? The code in your example prevents the transition from occurring at all, in my case at least.

Comment: @stackunderflow sure, you could perform the transition inside the `guard` by instead of `return transitionContext.completeTransition(false)`, simply put your fallback transition in there. But if the user tries to transition and the guard fails, for whatever reason, all the user would have to do is tap again. The end user will probably think the phone didn't register the tap and more likely blame the phone than the app.

Comment: But presumably, if I enter the guard failure block, that means the fromViewController and/or toViewController (or in my case, elements in the view controller hierarchy beneath them) are nil, so I can't really perform a fallback transition either

Comment: That's one reason I don't account for guard failure (but mostly because of rarity). I thought you had a non-animated transition in mind to fall back on.

Comment: Well oddly enough, if my dismissal animation guard statements fail, I can invoke `completeTransition` and the dismissal transition will occur without animation. But this is not the case for the presentation transition animation. I probably shouldn't care, because I can't conceive of a scenario where suddenly this code would fail at runtime, but just as a 'best practice', my instinct would be to safely unwrap the optionals and perform the transition without animation if necessary